# Recursion not properly running?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm practicing recursion, and am trying to use it to constantly add individual digits in a number until there is only 1 digit left.

Basically, if the number is `84`, it becomes `8+4 = 12` which then becomes `1 + 2 = 3`.

Below is my attempt on it. Not sure what I'm missing..

```
const weirdSum = (num) => {
  let result = 0;    
  const split = num.toString().split('');

  if(split.length > 1){
    for(let i=0;i<split.length;i++){
      result = result + (split[i]*1);
    }           
    weirdSum(result); // pass result as argument, which will be split.
  }

  return result; // return result if split.length is 1
}
```

Comment: should it be `return weirdSum(result);` ?

Comment: I tried return and it's also not working. And in regards to the second comment, thats true, but if its 2249 which is 17, then run the function again until you get 8. **second comment was deleted..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 2 mistakes, one you need to `return weirdSum(result);`
another you are returning `result` which is `0` you should return `num`

```js
const weirdSum = (num) => {
  let result = 0;    
  const split = num.toString().split('');

  if(split.length > 1){
    for(let i=0;i<split.length;i++){
      result = result + (split[i]*1);
    }           
    return weirdSum(result); // pass result as argument, which will be     split.
  }

  return num; // return result if split.length is 1
}

console.log(weirdSum(84));
```

Comment: There are many great answers here, but I chose this as the answer because it still uses my code; which helps me learn at the pace I'm learning right now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```js
let weirdSum = num => {  
  const split = num.toString().split('');

  if(split.length > 1){
    const sum = split.reduce((acc, it) => parseInt(it) + acc, 0)        
    return weirdSum(sum);
  }

  return num;
}

console.log(weirdSum(84));
console.log(weirdSum(123456));
```

Comment: It vastly improves an answer to include some explanatory text about why your solution works.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const weirdSum = (num) => {
  let result = 0;    
  const split = num.toString().split('');

  if(split.length > 1){
    for(let i=0;i<split.length;i++){
      result = result + (split[i]*1);
    }           
    return weirdSum(result); // pass result as argument, which will be split.
  }
  
  return split[0]; // return result if split.length is 1
}

console.log(weirdSum(84))
```

I just changed your codes to works properly, I have no idea it is optimized or not.
You need ti return the split[0] when recursion stack ends not the result!

Comment: Yes this happens always, we are human. Sometimes my mind hangs on simple conditions and sometimes solves complex problems. This is a natural human.

Answer (score 0):

This function isn't anonymous but it solves your problem

```
function weirdSum(num) {

    if(parseInt(num/10) == 0) {
        return num;
    }

    var num1 = 0;

    while(num != 0) {
        var d = parseInt(num%10);
        num1=num1+d;            
        num=parseInt(num/10);
    }

    return weirdSum(num1);

}
```

How it works ?

- Any single digit number when divided by 10 gives 0 as quotient ( parsing to int is required ), function exists when this condition is met ( the first if ).
- In the while loop I'm extracting digits of the number ( starting from the last digit ), when we divide a number by 10, the remainder is always the same as the last digit, then we are adding this to the new num ( num1 ).
- In the last step of the while loop, we are shortening the number by removing is last digit by dividing it by 10 and repacing the old num1 by quoatient.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const weirdSum = num => {
  // figure out the sum
  const sum = [...num + ""].reduce((a, e) => a + (e - 0), 0);
  // recurse if necessary
  return sum < 10 ? sum : weirdSum(sum);
}

console.log(weirdSum(84));
```